# MSCK not working through Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have created the hive context object and tried to execute the msck command which will add the partitions into hive table but it's giving the below exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
Operation not allowed: msck repair table(line 1, pos 0)

== SQL ==
msck repair table table_name
^^^

        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParserUtils$.operationNotAllowed(ParserUtils.scala:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlAstBuilder$$anonfun$visitFailNativeCommand$1.apply(SparkSqlParser.scala:837)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlAstBuilder$$anonfun$visitFailNativeCommand$1.apply(SparkSqlParser.scala:828)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParserUtils$.withOrigin(ParserUtils.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlAstBuilder.visitFailNativeCommand(SparkSqlParser.scala:828)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlAstBuilder.visitFailNativeCommand(SparkSqlParser.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.SqlBaseParser$FailNativeCommandContext.accept(SqlBaseParser.java:900)
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.AbstractParseTreeVisitor.visit(AbstractParseTreeVisitor.java:42)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder$$anonfun$visitSingleStatement$1.apply(AstBuilder.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder$$anonfun$visitSingleStatement$1.apply(AstBuilder.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParserUtils$.withOrigin(ParserUtils.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.visitSingleStatement(AstBuilder.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser$$anonfun$parsePlan$1.apply(ParseDriver.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser$$anonfun$parsePlan$1.apply(ParseDriver.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parse(ParseDriver.scala:82)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlParser.parse(SparkSqlParser.scala:46)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parsePlan(ParseDriver.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:582)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:682)
        at com.mcd.spark.driver.R2D2Driver$.main(R2D2Driver.scala:321)
        at com.mcd.spark.driver.R2D2Driver.main(R2D2Driver.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:729)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Created spark context and hive context like mentioned below.

```
 val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(appName).setMaster(master)
    var sc: SparkContext = null
    sc = new SparkContext(conf)
     val hqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)

hqlContext.sql("msck repair table table_name")

Can some one help me to solve how to add partitions into hive table?

Regards,
Aswin
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it with `"runSqlHive"` like:

```
hqlContext.runSqlHive("msck repair table table_name")
```

OR

```
try {
      Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");
      Connecton connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://<hostname>:<port>/<db_name>" , <user_name> , "");

      Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
      stmt.execute("msck repair table table_name");
      } catch (final ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
```

Comment: HiveContext is not showing this method. Do I need to import anything ?

Comment: It should be included in org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext? BTW what is spark and hive version ?

Comment: Versions are mentioned below

Hive 2.1.0-amzn-0
Spark version 2.0.0

I don't know why HiveContext is not able to show this method.

Comment: Seems in Spark 2.0 as SparkSession enabled, the method runSqlHive removed from HiveContext. v1.6.1  https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/HiveContext.html#runSqlHive(java.lang.String)  and v2.0.0 https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/HiveContext.html#runSqlHive(java.lang.String)

Comment: Any other alternative ?

Comment: try with jdbc connector the code snippet should be like in answer

Answer (score 1):

I think I ran into this sometime ago too. The support for MSCK was added in spark recently with support for fast stats. Can you try if the alternate syntax works for you?

`ALTER TABLE {table_name} RECOVER PARTITIONS;`

Also, you might want to have a look at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20697 to safeguard against the side-effects.